# WebJob having Timer trigger throws exception using Azure WebJobs SDK v3

Tags: azure, timer, triggers, sdk, cosmos

My Web Job throwing below exception. I recently updated the nuget packages. using azure webjobs sdk version 3.x.

I have a timer trigger function in the webJob

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" Version="1.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" Version="11.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue" Version="11.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.18" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.18" />
```

> fail: Host.Startup[0]
> The listener for function 'TimerTrigger' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The
> listener for function 'Functions.CheckUnreadTenantDataAsync' was
> unable to start.  ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot
> find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
> Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusAsync(String
> timerName)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
> stateMachine)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusAsync(String
> timerName)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Listeners.TimerListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Listener\TimerListener.cs:line
> 99    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonListener.cs:line
> 72    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line
> 69

Comment: Looks like you are missing assemblies. Your error message says that you are missing `'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`. You might want to add it.

Comment: @TomerShetah I recently updated my packages where I updated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage to Microsoft.Azure.Storage as Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 9.3 is deprecated